# How to erase elements from a vector of object?

Tags: c++, vector

I know how we can remove elements from a vector of int

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// .. put in some values ..
int int_to_remove = n;
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), int_to_remove), vec.end());
```

What if its a `vector<obj> vec` where obj is

```
class obj {

int ID;
string name;

}
```

How would I remove vectors that are holding onto a certain ID ?

```
std::vector<obj> vec;
// .. put in some values ..
int id_to_remove = n;
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.ID.begin(), vec.ID.end(), id_to_remove), vec.end());
```

Comment: remove calls destructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you are looking to delete objects matching a certain criteria, you need to use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of `std::remove`.

```
vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vec.ID.begin()
    ,   vec.ID.end()
    ,   [](const obj& x) {
            // ID needs to be public in order for this to compile
            return x.ID == id_to_remove;
        }
    )
,   vec.end()
);
```